# Pagination with next and previous

Tags: jquery

I have a piece of code that works to create pagination. But instead of showing the page numbers...I want to modify this code to rather show "next" and "previous". Any ideas of how I can do this?

[#lessons-table] is the ID of a HTML table with a list of table rows which appears above the function that creates the pagination. The table has 100+ rows. So far the function successfully displays 10 rows at a time...with page numbers underneath the table. I wish to remove the page numbers and display PREVIOUS and NEXT to flip through the pages.

```
function create_pagination(){
    $('#lessons-table').after('<div id="nav"></div>');
    var rowsShown = 10;
    var rowsTotal = $('#lessons-table tbody tr').length;

    var numPages = rowsTotal/rowsShown;
    for(i = 0; i < numPages; i++) {
        var pageNum = i + 1;
        $('#nav').append('<a href="#" rel="'+i+'">'+pageNum+'</a> ');
    }
    $('#lessons-table tbody tr').hide();
    $('#lessons-table tbody tr').slice(0, rowsShown).show();
    $('#nav a:first').addClass('active');
    $('#nav a').bind('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#nav a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var currPage = $(this).attr('rel');
        var startItem = currPage * rowsShown;
        var endItem = startItem + rowsShown;
        $('#lessons-table tbody tr').css('opacity','0.0').hide().slice(startItem, endItem).
        css('display','block').animate({opacity:1}, 800);
    });    
}
```

Comment: please post the html too so that we can understand whats happening

Comment: There is simply an HTML table above this function...with ID lessons-table. The table has a number of rows. The function will display 10 rows at a time.